# How to modify URL Query String without reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, url-rewriting, query-string

I'm using the following method to change the query URL parameter corresponding to the input/dropdown on a form. Currently `window.location.href` will cause a page reload on change. How can I integrate `history.replaceState()` instead to modify the URL without reloading?

**REGEX function**

```
function replaceQueryString(url, param, value) {
    var re = new RegExp("([?|&])" + param + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
    if (url.match(re))
        return url.replace(re, '$1' + param + "=" + value + '$2');
    else
        return url + '&' + param + "=" + value;
}
```

**On input change**

```
$("#input_field").on('change', function(e) {
    window.location.href = replaceQueryString(window.location.href, 'input_value', $(this).val());
});
```

**Update**

I've now managed to update the URL to the value `domain.com/2` on change, but how can I run it through the `replaceQueryString` function to parse it into `domain.com/?input_value=2`

```
$("#input_field").on('change', function(e) {
     window.history.replaceState("#input_field", "input_value", $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: @guest271314 it should be changing the URL to `domain.com/?input_value=3&next_filter_value=2` etc.

Comment: Where does code call `.replaceState()`?

Comment: It hasn't yet sorry, I was reading this would be the best method to use without page reload (Instead of `window.location.href`) but not sure how to implement.

Comment: @guest271314 please see the update to my question. Thanks!

Comment: What is issue with updated code?

Comment: @guest271314 I need it to run through the `replaceQueryString` function Regex to change the query string parameter.

Comment: What is preventing you from doing so?

Comment: @guest271314 that's the part I'm stuck with, including it into the `.replaceState` function.

Comment: `window.history.replaceState({}, "input_value", replaceQueryString(location.href, "input_value", $(this).val()))`?

Comment: @guest271314 that done it! Thanks, didn't realise you would use {} there :)

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: @guest271314 will do, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `replaceQueryString()` function to third parameter of `.replaceState()`

```
window.history.replaceState({}
, "input_value"
, replaceQueryString(location.href, "input_value", $(this).val()));
```